# Network adapter requires a reset every 20-25 minutes after installing mesh wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter, mesh-networking

After my household replaced their Nighthawk router with an Orbi mesh network, I have been experiencing regular network drops every 21 to 25 minutes on both my desktop and my laptop that require the network adapter to be reset in order for the connection to be restored.

Testing:

- These network outages appear to happen synchronously - when I boot up
  my laptop halfway through the 21-minute period, it also loses
  connection at roughly the same time my desktop does.
- The network issue does not happen when there are fewer
  programs being run - killing everything in task manager and
  monitoring the network does show some fluctuations every 21 or so
  minutes, but my devices manage to restore the connection automatically without
  requiring the adapter being reset if no or few programs are active.
- I haven't been able to isolate a singular program or application causing these issues - it just seems that at a certain point of adding programs to the pile, the network issues start to occur.
- I have confirmed that my Wifi-6 network card is compatible with the 802.11ax protocol used by the Orbi network, and signal strength has been consistently solid. Connection speeds are stable when the wifi is connected, as well.
- The network card has option "Turn device off to save power" turned off in its Advanced Settings.

I've been getting by by using a script that autodetects ping failures and resets the network adapter, but I'd really like to get to the bottom of this so I can support streaming and videoconferencing without having to worry about resetting the adapter three times an hour. Any ideas as to what's causing this or solutions for the issue would be very much appreciated!

System details:

- Windows 10 v2004 19041.630 64-bit
- Intel i9-9900K 3.60GHz
- Archer TX50E Wi-Fi 6 PCIe adapter

Comment: I am not entirely clear from reading your question if this happens with one kind of hardware, or different kinds of hardware (laptop + desktop). If the former, I'd guess: bug in the driver or firmware for mesh mode, e.g. memory leak or bit field overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This issue has been reproduced over two separate pieces of hardware: my laptop and my desktop. The laptop runs a lot of the same software as the desktop does, but to a lesser extent.

Comment: Sounds like the mesh is faulty. First try would be to return it as defective and get a replacement, otherwise it could be a design issue or even external interference.

Comment: Try updating the firmware in the mesh devices and the network drivers in all devices that attach to the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Making Orbi Great Again](https://windsorwebdeveloper.com/making-netgear-orbi-great-again/)
remarks that it's possible that the Orbi isn't the right choice for a medium-sized
house.

The solutions listed in the article:

1. Force the 2.4Ghz channel to 6 or 1
2. Set different SSIDs for 2.4 and 5 ghz
3. Decrease the transmit power
4. If you have a satellite connection, set a static IP for the satellite.

Comment: Thanks for the link - unfortunately solutions 1, 3 and 4 did not work, and solution 2 caused widespread drops across all other peripheral devices connected to the network, so perhaps the problem this solution tackles is not the one I am experiencing right now. Perhaps these solutions did not work because it looks like they were written for the Wifi 5 Orbi, while my household has installed a Wifi 6 Orbi with entirely different architecture.

Comment: Have you checked for firmware update? Somewhat unlikely, but check your router DHCP lease time setting.